# struggle with credentials file

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-machine

I'm about to deploy Docker container on AWS with credential file formatted like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY
aws_secret_access_key = KEY
region=eu-west-2
vpc-id=vpc-bb1b7fd3
```

and located in `~/.aws/credentials`

When I execute command `docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 app`
I get:

```
Couldn't determine your account Default VPC ID : "AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials\n\tstatus code: 401, request id: faf606d9-b12e-4a9e-a6c5-18eb609ffc45"
Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: amazonec2 driver requires either the --amazonec2-subnet-id or --amazonec2-vpc-id option or an AWS Account with a default vpc-id
```

Default VPC-ID is already defined. Anyone can help to resolve this or point me in the right direction ?

**Command I'm using**

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key AKIAyyy --amazonec2-secret-key AKIAxxx --amazonec2-region eu-west-2 --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-bb1b7fd3 flask_app
```

and when I'm trying to use credentials file located in my file system:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 flask_app
```

where `vpc-bb1b7fd3` was generated by AWS by default hence must be valid and time is correct too. I also tried to swap the keys in case I somehow managed to swap them but they're OK too. Output from `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` was identical with machine's system time.

Error says: `Error with pre-create check: "AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials\n\tstatus code: 401, request id: 9d642d91-cd93-4104-b9fb-2a42b1249e3b"`

**Tried:**
On Stack Exchange was very similar problem solved by restarting Docker daemon because Docker's clock stops syncing its time with computer's time when computer is in sleep and awaken again. I restarted Docker daemon with no change. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by downloading rootkey.csv from AWS and moving it into `~/.aws`
Docker instance is now uploaded onto AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with keys, so possible two reason

- Your system Time is wrong
- Invalid VPC ID

You should check your computer's clock maybe it's wrong, even though it it set to update "automatically from the internet." Try to Run the following will fix the computer's clock

`sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

Or run accordingly to your OS.

[AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/372)

The second reason seems like you are missing some flags in your command if time does not work then pls update the question with command.

**VPC ID**

> We determine your default VPC ID at the start of a command. In some
>   cases, either because your account does not have a default vpc, or you
>   don’t want to use the default one, you can specify a vpc with the
>   --amazonec2-vpc-id flag.
>
> Login to the AWS console Go to `Services -> VPC -> Your VPCs`. Locate
>   the VPC ID you want from the VPC column. Go to `Services -> VPC ->
>   Subnets`. Examine the `Availability Zone` column to verify that `zone` a
>   exists and matches your `VPC ID`. For example, `us-east1-a` is in the a
>   availability zone. If the a zone is not present, you can create a new
>   `subnet` in that zone or specify a `different zone` when you create the
>   machine.

To create a machine with a non-default VPC-ID:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key AKI******* --amazonec2-secret-key 8T93C********* --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-****** aws02
```

This example assumes the `VPC ID` was found in the a availability zone. Use the`--amazonec2-zone flag` to specify a zone other than the a zone. For example,`--amazonec2-zone c` signifies `us-east1-c`.

[docker-machine-with-aws-driver-amazon-web-services-from-docker-documentation](http://charmingwebdesign.com/docker-machine-with-aws-driver-amazon-web-services-from-docker-documentation/)

Comment: I'll probably have to contact AWS helpdesk. I don't wanna be stuck on this all week.

Comment: I noticed it's pretty common issue on the Internet. But solution isn't as common.